# Just check for existence in ALFA target clause

Tags: authorization, abac, alfa

I want write a target clause that says "If a certain attribute is set (oneAndOnly), then the policy applies". I have seen the [mustbepresent] thing, however, it always requires a comparator (like `==`).

This was my approch, but the syntax checker complains...

```
policy reportPolicies  {
        target  clause stringBagSize(my.company.person.doctor.id)==1        
}
```

I've seen you defining a string attribute "resourceType" but I don't like to define such a meta attribute. I'd rather like to check for existence of certain attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, great questions. Yes I often use an *artificial* attribute e.g. `resourceType` and compare it to values e.g. `medical record` or `transaction`. You do not have to do that because the attribute identifiers themselves convey the fact that you are dealing with one or another. However, I do think that it helps the policy be more readable.

On to the other issue: how to make sure an attribute has at least one value. In a Target element you can use the `mustBePresent` tag but I do not like it. If the attribute has no value, then the PDP returns `Indeterminate` and it short-circuits evaluation.

An alternative is to compare an attribute using > (greater than). For instance:

- `clause user.role > ""`
- `clause user.age>0`

That will force the value to be defined.

The cleaner way to do this, though, is to use bag functions inside a condition. For instance

```
condition stringBagSize(user.role)>0 // True if the user has at least one role
```

Comment: `target clause my.company.person.doctor.id[mustbepresent] > 0` looks like a hack. I'd only do it, if my PDP would perfom much faster instead of executing the condition. Thanks for the pointing towards the `condition` keyword in order to get the syntax right.

Comment: OK, the artificiat attribute `resourceType` also has its legitimacy because there is one place only to define the requested type. But I would change the type to `integer` to speed up performance while comparing.